# android app crashes and gives error in registration

Tags: java, android, json

I have in the process of developing a registration app using Android Studios, however once users try to register the application just says error in registration and the LogCat does not give any error, as well as when debugging the app, I still get no errors.

Please can you help and tell me where I am going wrong as the code is correct as it was working couple of months ago, however since I have returned from holiday it just says "Error occurred in registration".

User data gets entered into the database however it does not allow the user to move onto the next activity as it says "Error occurred in registration". Please can you help or advise?

LogCat

```
  01-07 15:14:42.933 2161-4203/com.Oakland E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value 2016-01-07 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-07 15:14:42.938 2161-2161/com.Oakland E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.Oakland, PID: 2161
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.Oakland.Register$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute(Register.java:211)
                                                                           at com.Oakland.Register$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute(Register.java:171)
```

Line 211- `if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {`

Register.Java

```
@Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {


        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(fname, lname, email, uname, password);

        return json;


    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            if (json != null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                if (json != null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null)
                registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                    pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");

                    registerErrorMsg.setText("Successfully Registered");


                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                    /**
                     * Removes all the previous data in the SQlite database
                     **/

                    UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                    logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                    /**
                     * Stores registered data in SQlite Database
                     * Launch Registered screen
                     **/

                    Intent registered = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registered.class);

                    /**
                     * Close all views before launching Registered screen
                     **/
                    registered.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    startActivity(registered);


                    finish();
                }

                else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("User already exists");
                }
                else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("Invalid Email id");
                }

            }


            else{
                pDialog.dismiss();

                registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occurred in registration");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        }
    }}
public void NetAsync(View view){
    new NetCheck().execute();
}}
```

UserFunction.Java

```
//URL of the PHP API

    private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/Register_api/";

private static String register_tag = "register";



    /**
         * Function to  Register
         **/
        public JSONObject registerUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String uname, String password){
            // Building Parameters
            List params = new ArrayList();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL,params);
            return json;
        }
```

Jsonpasar.java

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cloud_contacts";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static final String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String uname, String uid, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, fname); // FirstName
        values.put(KEY_LASTNAME, lname); // LastName
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_USERNAME, uname); // UserName
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }


    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("fname", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("lname", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("uname", cursor.getString(4));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(5));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(6));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }






    /**
     * Getting user login status
     * return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }


    /**
     * Re crate database
     * Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your json?

Comment: My Json works fine as Login function works. I have now added the Json.

Comment: What exactly is `jsonParser` and what does the `getJSONFromUrl(...)` method do.

Comment: I have now added the jsonparser code and the getJsonFromUrl gets the information from user.function.java.

Comment: From the logs that you've posted, it seems that the value returned by the server can't be converted to a `JSONObject`. I'm not sure why that is because the `String` that appears before this error message seems to have the correct format.

Comment: I have been working on this for months now and have asked others, they still cannot figure out the error as their is no error. Could you help or advise please?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Jackson to create JSON strings. You just set object and convert to json string. Also converting to object is easy.

Error is connected with parsing error. Hmm. That's weird. You say user is added to database but if "Error occurred in registration" shows, code with addUser couldn't be executed because it's inside if. I don't get application flow :( Can you tell more in comment? 
Also "registerUser" doesn't register user but only create json as I see.

```
db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
```

Comment: Could you please help or advise? When ever I register new user it just says error occurred in registration, however the user details are entered into the database and once I login with user details it allows me to login.

Comment: I really would like to help but I have to understand app code flow.
In background you only create JsonObject. 
In background you check (twice!) is it's ok(? I'm using other lib ;)). If not you get message "Error occurred in registration". So how user could be added to DB if code didn't get inside IF condition with db.addUser?

Comment: Databasehandler.java inserts the data into the database using SQLite.

Comment: Ok. I don't understand your code. Back to problem. Did you upgraded json lib version? Server changed format of responses? Your json string looks ok. No special chars. 
You are using "iso-8859-1" Try with UTF-8

Comment: I have tried with both and still getting same message. I have tried to use this tutorial as well which is still not helping http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/08/develop-android-login-registration-with-php-mysql.html. Please help?

Comment: That's not best tutorial. He's using deprecated and deleted in 6.0 methods (HTTPClient). In marshmallow your code won't work. 
Solution for that is rewrite code and use Retrofit which have integrated parser.
Can you set breakpoint at "Log.e("JSON", json);" in JsonParser and show screen with json value?

Comment: Still not showing anything. could you please help or advise?.

Comment: Please add screenshot with values from debuging. 
" Can you set breakpoint at "Log.e("JSON", json);" in JsonParser and show screen with json value?"

Comment: How do I do this as the debugging process is very slow and shows a blank screen for hours and hours.  When running the application it runs in straightaway, however debugging takes hours and a lot of time.

Comment: Do you have any breakpoint on method? It should work fast and just stop on breakpoint.

Comment: when evaluating the expression it says that the result is unidentified. Could you please me how shall I debug it and what do I need to look at in particular in the variables.

Comment: I have now posted and edited the new logcat which i am getting now.  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.Oakland.Register$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute(Register.java:211)
                                                                           at com.Oakland.Register$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute(Register.java:

Comment: You really have to use debug. I don't know how but you have to. Try to change emulator or device. 
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html

Comment: Wat do I need to look at while I debug the device. Do I look at the variables or threads.

Comment: You have never did debugging? Check "json" vadiable value. Paste it here or add screenshot

Comment: Could you please tell me where shall I put the break point and which variable do I need to look when I debug the application to find the error.

Comment: Mistic I have debugged this and found that username is returning null value. could you please help and advise how I can fix the username field.